# Eclipse rcp - how to load jdbc driver?

Tags: jdbc, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was wondering if someone could give me some instructions on how to do the following:

1. How to add mysql connection JAR file to the Eclipse plugin build path
2. How to add the connector JAR file as library and adding to the plugin's runtime classpath

I am getting com.mysql.jdbc.Driver exception when trying to load the Driver class using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. I have added the jdbc driver to the project by right clicking on the project name and selecting add Library button. But I found out there for eclipse rcp project there is a different way of adding the jdbc jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used mysql with Eclipse, but i've done this with postgres sql. Maybe this will help you:

- Right-click project in Package explorer
- Build path
- Add external archives...
- Select your mysql jar archive
- Press OK
- The library should be now referenced in the "Referenced Librairies" under the Package explorer. Now try to run your program again.

Comment: this is completely wrong. by doing this, jar file will not be added to the bundle classpath. such plugin project will maybe work once started from the IDE. but will definitely fail if plugin is exported and run as a part of RCP application.

Comment: i'm not an expert but i managed to make it work by setting the classpath on the java command line. i'm sure there are other options though.

Comment: try to export this such plugin (or an rcp application) and see if it will work. and if you will try to update classpath with "PDE Tools / Update classpath" - library added directly to the project will dissappear, because it it not mentioned in the bundle manifest.

be aware, we are talking about Plugin/RCP project. If it would be a a plain java project - then your solution will be 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

Add your jdbc driver jar to the bundle classpath (every RCP plugin is a OSGi bundle). To do it you can edit META-INF/MANIFEST.MF directly or use manifest editor provided by PDE (classpath section under Runtime tap).

In general, you should never edit plugin projects classpath directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. run "PDE Tools / Update classpath";
2. the mysql jar must in the project lib dir.
3. in project "Java build path", select the mysql jar in lib dir of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Do use `DynamicImport-Package: *` in the MANIFEST.MF of the jar-plugin having mysql.jar as Runtime classpath.
It helps `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` importing wanted packages.

Comment: In fact mysql jar is a bundle, if you remove Bundle entries of its MANIFEST.MF, you can use Class.forName("...") from your plugin-jar as for hsqldb.jar