# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. two program in one project ,one can work but the other can not

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, eclipse-rcp, classnotfoundexception

I know that there have been so many questions on this theme, but I feel the situation I am facing is really different.
The question:
I have created an RCP project, in which I need to connect to my Mysql database. Before I wrote my program, I wrote a test program to test the configuration needed, and I connected to my Mysql database successfully. The test program can be found in Appendix 1.
Then I began to write my program in the same project, but when I called the function in it, the exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` happened. It really disturbed me. The program can be seen in Appendix 2.

### Appendix 1 Sql.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Sql
{

    private static final String MYSQL_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/manager?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root"; 
    private static final String PASSWORD = "yhl0821";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement sm = null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName(MYSQL_DRIVER);
            con =DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Successed to connect the mysql!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

### Appendix 2 EventEntity.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class EventEntity
{
    private static final String MYSQL_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/manager?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "yhl0821";
public static List<Object> getEventEntity()
    {
        List<Object> list = null;//
        Connection con = null;
        Statement sm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName(MYSQL_DRIVER); //this is the setence creating exception
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Successed to connect the mysql!");
            sm = con.createStatement();
            rs = sm.executeQuery("select * from systemevent ");//
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return list;

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse rcp - how to load jdbc driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956936/eclipse-rcp-how-to-load-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 0):

The class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is not on your CLASSPATH when you run the program in Appendix 2.

Comment: but how can i put the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` on the CLASSPATH when i run the program in Appendix 2. Is there any different from the program in Appendix 1

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on how you are running the program in Appendix 2. For example, from a terminal, from Eclipse, from Netbeans, etc.

Comment: probably you need to include the jar file, containing this class to class path or build library path ( mostly like mysql-connector-java***.jar)

Comment: Thans for your attention. I run the two program both with Eclipse.EventEntity.java is one file of my RCP project,i use it when i debug the rcp project as "Eclipse Application",and i run the "Sql.java" as a java Application to test whether it can connect to my database.Beg your advices .Thanks!

Comment: yes ,I am sure i have done what you adviced ,but the problem still exists.haha...

Answer (score 0):

Prior to now,i did not understand the meaning of Classpath in the RCP project run from Eclipse. if you want to write and  run a RCP project with Eclipse ,you should not only put the *.jars and other files you need in build path(they are needed when the program is compiled),but also configure Classpath in "Runtime" .you can configure it like this:1、dobble click the plugin.xml.2、choose Runtime and find the Classpath.3、click ‘Add’ to put the files what the RCP project needs when you run it.